# Does loading a view effectively stop a controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Would the following code in a controller prevent the nextFunction() from running?

```
$this->load->view('foo');
nextFunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ostensibly, that seems to be the case.  Apparently, CI will combine calls to multiple views into one response, so that you can assemble a page (response) from multiple pieces.  However, that doesn't mean that it returns control to the controller.

You can have the call to `load` return that processed view as a string.  That has to allow you to do further processing in the controller.

e.g.

```
$foo_string = $this->load->view('foo', '', false);
nextFunction();
```

This would require that you echo $foo_string yourself, so that it's displayed in the browser.

See "Returning views as data" at the very bottom of [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), in the CI user guide.